# How can i exclude parsing events by kv filter which does not match pattern

Tags: elasticsearch, filter, logstash, kivy-language

I am parsing logs from many daemons of UTM solution.
Grok and kv config looks like:

```
 grok {
      match => [ "message", "%{SYSLOGPROG} %{NOTSPACE:syslog_hostname} %{DATA:syslog_program}(?:\[%{POSINT:syslog_pid}\])?: %{GREEDYDATA:syslog_message}" ]
    }
    kv {
      id => "syslogkv"
      source => "syslog_message"
      trim_key => " "
      trim_value => " "
      value_split => "="
      field_split => " "
    }
```

Usually events looks like

```
    <30>2019:04:23-20:13:38 hostname ulogd[5354]: id="2001" severity="info" sys="SecureNet" sub="packetfilter" name="Packet dropped" action="drop" fwrule="60002" initf="eth3.5" outitf="eth5" srcmac="c8:9c:1d:af:68:7f" dstmac="00:1a:8c:f0:f5:23" srcip="x.x.x.x" dstip="y.y.y.y" proto="17" length="56" tos="0x00" prec="0x00" ttl="63" srcport="5892" dstport="53"
```

and parsed without any problem

But when some daemons generates events looking like (WAF in example)

```
<139>2019:04:23-16:21:38 hostname httpd[1475]: [security2:error] [pid 1475:tid 3743300464] [client x.x.x.x] ModSecurity: Warning. Pattern match "([\\\\~\\\\!\\\\@\\\\#\\\\$\\\\%\\\\^\\\\&\\\\*\\\\(\\\\)\\\\-\\\\+\\\\=\\\\{\\\\}\\\\[\\\\]\\\\|\\\\:\\\\;\\"\\\\'\\\\\\xc2\\xb4\\\\\\xe2\\x80\\x99\\\\\\xe2\\x80\\x98\\\\`\\\\<\\\\>].*?){8,}"
```

my output breaks and logstash stops processing any logs.
How can i exclude kv parsing events by regexp or any pattern?
In simple words - do not use kv if first words in syslog_message begins with "[" or any other regexp.

Comment: If i exclude these events from kv filter, it doesn't parse events. 
Help me please to write filter for events, which begins with "[" character and contains events like:`[field:string] [field:string] [field string]` also may contain random data which i dont want to parse between `[][]` 
For example: `[field:string] randomdata [field:string]`

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your kv filter in a conditional on the field:

```
if [syslog_message] !~ /^\[/ {
    kv { }
}
```

Comment: shouldn't it looks like
```if [syslog_message] !~ /^\[/ {
    kv { }
}```
?

Comment: Corrected to reverse the conditional.

Comment: If i exclude these events from kv filter, it doesn't parse events. Help me please to write filter for events, which begins with "[" character and contains events like:`[field:string] [field:string] [field string]` also may contain random data which i dont want to parse between `[][]` For example: `[field:string] randomdata [field:string]`

Comment: I think you have three choices: (1) change the original output to be a better format; (2) convert the output into something that can be parsed by kv{}; (3) create your own grok pattern for the message.  I'd go for #1 or #3.